# How to locate crashes in react-native project caught by firebase crashlyitics

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

i deployed my project to production and i configured firebase crashlytics for that app. some crashes happened and firebase crashlytics caught those, but how can i locate those crashes in my project

[image]

how can i locate above crash in my project, is there any way to locate above error, i need to info like in which file the error happening, please help me to locate the error